# Construct dictionary with array value instead of serialized JSON string

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, json, json-serialization

I have some data from the bind grid view and I want to display them in a serialized format. Right now I have a nested array where the above parent is serialized correctly but the child array has escape characters and slashes.

```cs
private List<string[]> gridDataList = new List<string[]>();

private void BindGridView()
{
    string ss = cb_DOCUMENT_NO.SelectedValue;
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> MainList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    Dictionary<string, string> rowData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    rowData["User_id"] = user_id;
    rowData["Region_Id"] = txt_REGION_ID.Text;
    rowData["document_no"] = ss;
    rowData["industry_name"] = cb_INDUSTRY_NAME.SelectedValue;
    rowData["customer_number"] = cb_INDUSTRY_NAME.SelectedValue;
    rowData["posting_date"] = txt_POSTING_DATE.Text;

    List<Dictionary<string, string>> paymentList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    foreach (GridViewRow row in biGridView.Rows)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> paymentData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            string headerText = biGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text.Trim();
            string cellText = row.Cells[i].Text.Trim();

            if (cellText == "&nbsp;")
            {
                cellText = string.Empty;
            }

            paymentData[headerText] = cellText.Trim();
        }

        paymentList.Add(paymentData);
    }

    rowData["payment_for"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paymentList);
    string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rowData, Formatting.Indented);

    Response.Write("<pre>" + jsonData + "</pre>");
    PostJsonDataInLaravelApp(jsonData);
}
```

Obtained output:

```
{
  "User_id": "EAUSER02",
  "Region_Id": "ID-02",
  "document_no": "02-80/81-BIN-00259",
  "industry_name": "02-CNO-0001",
  "customer_number": "02-CNO-0001",
  "posting_date": "03-05-2080",
  "payment_for": "[{\"BillType\":\"गोदाम भवन बहाल\",\"Description\":\"गोदाम भवन बहाल\",\"Amount\":\"1000.00\",\" \":\"\"}]"
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "User_id": "EAUSER02",
  "Region_Id": "ID-02",
  "document_no": "02-80/81-BIN-00259",
  "industry_name": "02-CNO-0001",
  "customer_number": "02-CNO-0001",
  "posting_date": "03-05-2080",
  "payment_for": [
    {
      "BillType": "गोदाम भवन बहाल",
      "Description": "गोदाम भवन बहाल",
      "Amount": "1000.00",
      " ": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would say `Dictionary<string, string>` type is not a good choice. Based on your expected output, you need to store the `paymentList` as array but not as serialized string.

Instead, you should declare the `rowData` as `Dictionary<string, object>` to allow the key-value pair to store the array value.

```cs
Dictionary<string, object> rowData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

And you can store the `paymentList` value as array.

```cs
rowData["payment_for"] = paymentList;
```